# frequency count of states in multiple columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-columns, plyr, frequency

I have a table that looks like this:

```
City  Browser   Device    Channel        Category
A     IE        mobile    International  Fashion
A     safari    mobile    Link           Furniture
B     chrome    desktop   Link           Fashion
B     opera     tablet    Direct         Gift
C     IE        desktop   Direct         Health
C     Kindle    console   Email          Health
C     Chrome    console   Email          Fashion
```

What I need is to get a frequency of each of the sub -headings against the main heading which is `Category`:

```
Category  Sub Category  Variable        Value 
Health    Device        mobile          25%
Health    Device        console         40%
Health    Device        desktop         25%
Health    Device        tablet          10% 
Health    Channel       International   80%
Health    Channel       Direct          20%
Fashion
Gift
```

So on for the other categories. Post this I want to create a segmented barplot based on `Category` and each sub category. Incase I don't get the frequency, count is fine since I can convert to a frequency in the ggplot.

Answer (score 2):

(I added a few more lines to the data file example)

Is this what you're going for?:

```
dat <- read.table(text="City  Browser   Device    Channel        Category
A     IE        mobile    International  Fashion
A     safari    mobile    Direct         Furniture
A     safari    console   Email          Health
B     chrome    desktop   Link           Fashion
B     opera     tablet    Direct         Gift
B     opera     mobile    Link           Furniture
C     opera     console   Direct         Gift
C     IE        desktop   Direct         Health
C     Kindle    console   Email          Health
C     Chrome    console   Email          Fashion", 
                  header=TRUE, stringsAs=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  gather(`Sub Category`, `Variable`, Device, Channel) %>%
  count(`Category`, `Sub Category`, `Variable`)

## Source: local data frame [16 x 4]
## Groups: Category, Sub Category
## 
##     Category Sub Category      Variable n
## 1    Fashion       Device       console 1
## 2    Fashion       Device       desktop 1
## 3    Fashion       Device        mobile 1
## 4    Fashion      Channel         Email 1
## 5    Fashion      Channel International 1
## 6    Fashion      Channel          Link 1
## 7  Furniture       Device        mobile 2
## 8  Furniture      Channel        Direct 1
## 9  Furniture      Channel          Link 1
## 10      Gift       Device       console 1
## 11      Gift       Device        tablet 1
## 12      Gift      Channel        Direct 2
## 13    Health       Device       console 2
## 14    Health       Device       desktop 1
## 15    Health      Channel        Direct 1
## 16    Health      Channel         Email 2
```